# Trying to login to wp-admin gives blank page with a text string: "Blocked"

Tags: php, wordpress, admin, web-hosting

When clicking login at my site.com/wp-admin, I get redirected to a blank page with a single text string:

> blocked

**Info**:
I am using Wordpress and my hosting provider one.com.
I've read about people that couldn't access the login screen, but in my case I could access it, but whatever credentials I use I still get redirected to the "blank" blocked site.

Since I'm new and still learning I accidentally tried to connect to one.com instead of mysite's FTP server. This made One.com block my IP from entering my site.

I contacted them and told them that I'm new and faulty sent connection requests to them (probably thought it was a DoS attack). They unblocked me, so I now can access my site. But of course a new problem arouse: I get a blocked message when trying to login (with any credentials, even blank). All the (admin)users get the same message.

Answer (score 10):

One.com has added a special policy to reduce spam on wordpress websites.
You have to change your .htaccess file and add these rules

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
RewriteRule .* - [CO=wordpress_test_cookie:WP+Cookie+check:%    {HTTP_HOST}:1440:/]
```

http://one-docs.com/guides/en/wordpress-login-blocked/